# How to stop the entire java webapp when the servlet fails to initialize

Tags: servlets, exception

I want my web application to fail on startup if any of my servlet fails to initialize.
I would expect if I throw an exception form the `Servlet.init()` method it would cause the entire app to fail, but apparently it doesn't. The web container (Tomcat 7 in my case) just fails to load that particular servlet, but the application is reported to be successfully deployed anyway.

It behaves as expected if an exception thrown from e.g. `ServletContextListener.contextInitialized()` method, but why the exception thrown from the `Servlet.init()` doesn't have this effect?

Is there any way to stop the application in case of a Servlet initialization error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this following steps:

1. Keep your servlet in load-on-startup list such that your servlet
   is initialized on application start.
2. In Servlet.init() method, set an attribute in ServletContext saying the servlet is initialzied. ex, *myServletInited*
3. Implement ServletContextListener.contextInitialzied() method. Check if *myServletInited* is present. If is does not present throw an exception which fails the application.

Comment: I don't think this works as the contextInitialized gets called before Servlet.init() but if contextInitialized fails it terminates the whole app.